# Choose Argument position for scipy minimise

Tags: python, function, scipy, minimize

I have a function defined as follows

```
def function(a, b, c, d):
    ### some calculation
    return output
```

I was to use `scipy.minimise` to minimize the output with respect to variable `a` alone. Is there a way to tell it to just solve for the first variable (while keeping `b`, `c` and `d` constant).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html):

> The objective function to be minimized: `fun(x, *args) -> float`

and

> `argstuple`, optional: Extra arguments passed to the objective function and its derivatives (`fun`, `jac` and `hess` functions).

So simply use a wrapper (or rewrite the definition and the first lines in your function):

```
def functionWrapper(x, args):
    a = x
    b,c,d = args
    return function(a,b,c,d)
```

And the minimization call

```
minimize(functionWrapper,initialGuess,(bValue,cValue,dValue,));
```

where `bValue`,`cValue`,`dValue` are the constant values for the coefficients.